# Check if Two Values Share a Row Anywhere on an Entire Sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to return a Boolean (or count) if two values share 1 row (or more) on an *entire* page.

The two values could be in any order on that row. 
They are not neatly organized in static, predictable columns.

So if we have cells containing:

```
abc 111 ghi 
ghi 222 abc 
jlk 333 xyz
```

I want it to return "true" (or 2, since there are 2 shared rows) when I check for "abc AND ghi".
Similarly, a check for "jlk AND xyz" would return 1/true.

But if I was to check for "111 and 222" it would return 0/False, because they do not share a row.

I've found good support for sumproduct() and countifs() methods to do this, but the techniques were difficult to adapt to an entire page that does not have information organized in predictable columns.

Comment: Do you specify values to search for somewhere? Or do you want to test any value that is present?

Comment: I will be specifying the values somewhere. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how many columns you want to work with but this answer might put you on the right path.

[Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and return a value in the same row but different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147803/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-return-a-value-in-the-same-row/15148396)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following array formula:

```
{=SUM(--(MMULT(($A$1:$D$3=$F$2)+($A$1:$D$3=$G$2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)^0))>1))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

**Edit 2:**

To count only if both values are in the same row regardless of number.

```
{=SUM(--(MMULT(--($A$1:$D$3=$F$2);TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)^0))>0)*(MMULT(--($A$1:$D$3=$G$2);TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)^0))>0))}
```

Comment: I believe this is a near-perfect solution, which I could likely still adapt, but it does not account for duplicate data. 
With your example data, it works. If I, however, remove "ghi" and replace it with another "abc", it counts the row (even though the row lacks "ghi").

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice it. Then the formula will be a little more complicated, See edit.