# Excel: Looping value returns from responses into a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I made a Google Form to collect choices on subjects. On column B of the Responses sheet there are the names of the responses. On cell C2 of the Block Name List sheet is the lookup value. The function filters through column K to look for matches, then returns the names from column B. I want to make a list of names for each choice as seen here [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrvAr.jpg)

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147803/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-return-a-value-in-the-same-row/15148396) and got

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Responses!$B:$B,MATCH(C$2,Responses!$K:$K,0),1),"No Match")`

but this does only accommodates for the first entry that matches the criteria. How should this be changed to suit this situatiion?

Comment: You mentioned Google Form. Do you mean Google Sheets? If so, you can use `Query`, or `Filter`. Depending on what version of Excel you could also use `Filter` there.

Comment: I used google forms to input data into the google sheets. I want to make it so the list fills up automatically upon data entry