# Excel: how to move “answers” rows into under column “questions”?

Tags: excel-formula

How do I move answers from other column to same question under another column, can any one guide the exact formula to achieve this? See example below what needs to be achieved as shown in picture.
[image: Excel]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and return a value in the same row but different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147803/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-return-a-value-in-the-same-row)

Comment: Could you more accurately describe where you want the result. If your data starts in `Sheet1` cell `A2`, where do you want the result, e.g. starting in `Sheet2` cell `A2` with one empty row in between?

Answer (score 0):

With having the data as posted in your example, use the following formula in A10:
`=IF(OR(OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-7)/3,0),,,)=A9,OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-7)/3,0),1,,)=A9), IF(OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-7)/3,0),1,,)=A9,"",OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-7)/3,0),1,,)),OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-7)/3,0),,,))`

But there may be a simpler way..