# Excel: Return the value of a few rows above in the same column if the value meets criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a significant mind blank when trying to suss this one out.

I want to return the date from a few rows above if a cell contains a certain value.

Image 1: [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QitGE.png)
Image 2: How I want it to look [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWuPY.png)

I tried using a similar sum to the one in this thread... but it didn't work: [Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and return a value in the same row but different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147803/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-return-a-value-in-the-same-row)

Comment: The screenshot you have attached has cut off the column names and row numbers. Please attach a new image with these included. Additionally, it would help to have a second image of the desired result (just fill the values in manually).

Comment: Hi Craig, this doesn't seem to be about programming as far as I can tell. Consider asking on https://superuser.com instead. That being said, your screenshot mentions "Column E" but your column headers are not visible in the screenshot... might want to fix that, at least.

Comment: Thanks - I have amended the screen grabs

Comment: An `=XLOOKUP()` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values in column F increase through to the end of the year (week 1, week 2, etc)

The formula you are looking for is `XLOOKUP`. This allows you specify a value to search for (`"N"`), the array of values to search (`$Fn:$AAn`, where `n` is the same row), the array of values to extract (`$F$3:$AA$3`, the dates of each week) and what to return when no result is found (e.g. `"N/A"` or `""`).

The formula in cell E5 will be:

```
=XLOOKUP("N", $F5:$AA5, $F$3:$AA$3, "N/A", 0, 1)
```